# Construct a bijective map and prove it is bijective

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

S is a finite set with more than 1 element. Construct a bijective map $f:S\times \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ and prove it is bijective. ($\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers)

I'm at a lost at how to solve this. Wouldn't the cardinality of the domain be higher than the range? If so, then how is it possible to create a bijective function?

Comment: No, the cardinailty of both sides is $\aleph_0$.

Comment: It may (or may not) be easier to think of a bijection in the other direction. Hint: Think of division with remainder, and let $|S|$ be the divisor.

Comment: Visually, list the elements of $S \times \mathbb Z$ as a rectangular table. Then find a way to count them.

Answer (score 2):

You can come up with a bijection between the two sets, and for that reason they will have the same cardinality. It does seem like the domain should be bigger, but you can use a similar trick as you do to show that the integers and the rationals are the same cardinality (countable).

Imagine $S = {s_1, s_2, ..., s_n}$, with n finite. Then, have $f(s_1,1) = 1, f(s_2,1) = 2, ..., f(s_n,1) = n, f(s_1, 2) = n+1,$ etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Would f(Sx, y) = (y-1)n+x me sufficient? And would saying that every element of SxZ is mapped to a unique element in Z sufficient for explaining that it's surjective?

Comment: Oops. My above answer only works if we use $\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$. Try to think of how you would adapt that to work for the integers instead. To show that a function is surjective, you actually need to show that each element in the range gets mapped to by some element in the domain. The condition you explained is for showing a function is injective (one to one).

Comment: Would my function work for negatives (or for simplification: f=yn+x) ? Say y is a negative number; the value pair would appropriately get mapped to a unique negative value

Comment: Oh yes! You are right.